# Is it possible to remove (.:format) from from routes for my resources)? rails2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

if I do `map.resources :users` in routes.rb, the routes I get have (.:format) at the end of each route (rake routes).

How do I get rid of this in rails 2.3?

I'm pretty sure in 3.1.1 I can do something like :format=>false. Is this available in 2.3? Is there a monkey patch I can do to mimic :format=>false?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just ignore it (i.e. don't respond based on the format)?

Comment: it's conflicting with other routes. at the bottom level, x.com/username goes to that user's profile. at a higher level, there's a route: x.com/foo. I've disallowed usernames that conflict with higher level routes (using validates_exclusion_of), however, if a user signs up with a user name of foo.bar, x.com/foo.bar will go to the top level route instead of the user profile. Plus it's throwing off my 404 pages cuz it can't find an error template of that format. plus on a philosophical note, rails shouldn't hijack the period in its routing. It's trying to do to much.

Comment: So, why not put your users behind another level, such as `x.com/users/foo` ? This would be the typical way to structure the routes (`/controller/action` or in your case `/users/username`), and usernames would then not cause collisions between higher level routes.

Comment: The answer's definitely "no" btw. I'm working on a monkey patch to resources.rb to get it done. Will post if/when I get it working. I'm becoming less and less a fan of both ruby and rails the more I get to know it.

Comment: Well, Rails is more of a 'convention over configuration' way of doing things, and it is very opinionated. As such it tends to be easier to stick with the standards whenever possible, but we are programmers, so to each his own.

Comment: cuz it's a social site and we want them to play a prominent role in our urls (e.g. facebook.com/username or quora.com/username). edit: to end of the discussion: agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monkey patched. Blah. I *really, really* wanted to change the default behavior, but took into consideration potential future developers' sensitivities.

`map.resource(s) ..., :format=>false` now doesn't include the format in the route

config/initializers/resources.rb:

```
module ActionController
  module Resources
    private
      def map_resource_routes(map, resource, action, route_path, route_name = nil, method = nil, resource_options = {} )
        if resource.has_action?(action)
          action_options = action_options_for(action, resource, method, resource_options)
          formatted_route_path = (resource.options[:format] == false ? route_path : "#{route_path}.:format")

          if route_name && @set.named_routes[route_name.to_sym].nil?
            map.named_route(route_name, formatted_route_path, action_options)
          else
            map.connect(formatted_route_path, action_options)
          end
        end
      end
  end
end
```

The change I made is here:

```
formatted_route_path = (resource.options[:format] == false ? route_path : "#{route_path}.:format")
```

It used to just be `formatted_route_path = "#{route_path}.:format"`

To get it to apply to all routes, in routes.rb, I just wrapped all routes with `map.with_options :format=>false do |map| ... end`