# Rails Routing having a URL in the query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I need to hit a url like mydomain.com/proxies/www.msn.com in order to fulfill some ajax requests for an API

In my route I have

```
get "/proxies/:url" => "proxies#get"
```

and I in the controller I have

```
url_contents = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(params[:url]))
```

which if i put /proxies/www i get

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x3f89508 URL:www>
```

if i put /proxies/www.msn.com

I get

No route matches [GET] "/proxies/www.msn.com"

Comment: are you using **`rails-3.*`**? Seems discrepancies between your tags and route.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems here:

1. You're trying to treat a URL without a scheme as an HTTP URL.
2. Your `/proxies` route won't match `:url`s with dots and slashes the way you're expecting it to.

For the first one, you'll have to add the schema manually:

```
url = 'http://' + params[:url]
content = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
```

For the second one, you can use a splat-route to deal with embedded slashes and `:format => false` to keep Rails from trying to treat `.com`, for example, as a format:

```
get '/proxies/*url' => 'proxies#get', :format => false
```

If you use `:url`, Rails will see embedded slashes as component separators and that's probably not what you want. Without the the [`:format => false`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing), Rails will try to interpret `.X` (for any `X`) as a format (just like `.html`, `.json`, ...) rather than as part of the URL.

Comment: Great! But i could apply this way in rails 3 only. What is recommended for rails 2? I got this *http://stackoverflow.com/a/7782283/1160106* but still unclear.

Comment: @Samiron: AFAIK the `*url` would [behave the same](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#route-globbing) in Rails2. You might be able to replace the `:format => false` with `:requirements => { :url => /.*/ }` to get around the dot issue.

Answer (score 0):

***This is applicable for rails-2***

The problem is with the `dot(.)` I guess. Ive tried something like below and it worked.

```
#routes.rb
map.get_proxy 'proxies/:url', :controller => "Proxies", :action => "get", :requirements => { :url => /.*/ }

#view file
#Here dot(.) are needed to replace with its encoded string %2E
<%= link_to 'Get The Site', get_proxy_url('www.msncom') %>


#Proxies Controller
#After receiving the url the %2E need to conovert to dot(.) again.
url_contents = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://'+params[:url]))
```

modified as stated by *@mu*.

Comment: There are better ways: `:format => false` or `:constraints => { :url => /.*/ }`.

Answer (score -1):

```
match '/proxies/:url' => 'proxies#get', :as => :proxies_get
```